# Return type from db methods

Tags: c#

What return type should one return from a method that is getting rows from the database.  Should you keep the data in a dataset / datatable, should you create a collection of objects representing the data, or should you return an interface such as IList or IEnumerable, etc?

I know the real answer is "it depends", but I am just curious as to best practices that others observe.  Dataset / datatable seems the simplest, but returning an interface seems to be the way it should be done.  How are you all doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically a collection of objects exposed via IList<T> or IEnumerable<T>, but [why](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html) [do](http://subsonicproject.com/) [the](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) [work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx) yourself?